# http response codes - broken links automated checker returning many working 0 responses

Tags: http

I have set up a cron job that is running through a large site and finding links. we then test for http response codes occasionally looking for codes = 0 or codes > 499.

The problem is I am getting a lot of http response codes 0 for pages that exist perfectly fine. on the other hand, i think it is important to have the 0 code for a website that has been completely removed isn't it?

Hope someone can advise! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "0" code in HTTP.

You'll need to provide more details about how the checker is implemented.

Comment: I am using drupal_http_request from drupal 7. The function doing the call is specified here http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7 I guess using fopen from php?